# Using multiple input statements with if/else

Tags: python, if-statement, input, logic

I am trying to create a simple program based on what mode of transport people should take to work if it is raining depending on how far they live:

```
< 2km = "walk"
> 10km = "bus"
>= 2km and <=10km = "bike"
```

I have worked out the first bit (well at least I think I have), but I'm stuck as to how to integrate the different if statements for the different distances. So once a person answers "no" to the question "is it raining today", they then have to enter an integer number for how far they live from work and based on this it will tell them what mode of transport to take.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
`weather = input("Is it raining today? ")
if weather == "yes":
print("You should catch the bus to work.")
elif weather == "no":
input("How far in km do you need to travel? ")`
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems trivial. You just need to compare last input with 2, 10 and print the result depending on comparison

Answer (score 0):

With such input data there're two possible basic solutions:

```
def travel_choice(input)
return {
    < 2 : “walk”;
    2 > and < 10 : “bike”;
    10 < : “bus"
} [input]
```

or

```
def travel_choice(input)
if (input < 2 and input > 0)
    “walk”
elif(input > 2 and input < 10)
    “bike”
elif “bus"
```

Hopefully this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thank guys, that's a great help (sorry I am new to Python). I think just getting the two input statements working was the main issue, but I think this should solve my issue:

```
weather = input("Is is currently raining today? ")
if weather == "yes":
    print("You should take the bus to work.")
elif weather == "no":
  x = int(input("How far in km do you live from work? "))
  if x < 2:
      print("You should walk to work.")
  if x >10:
      print("You should catch the bus to work.")
  elif x >=2 and x <= 10:
      print("You should ride your bike to work.")
```